# Dot net dll path when compiling c# code inside an azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

What path do I use to reference framework dlls in an azure function?

When compiling c# code within a c# application using the CSharpCompilation class I specify metadata references to framework dlls providing the full path as in the example below where the path is "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.4\".  I am wanting to port this functionality to an azure function and am not sure what path I must use to reference the framework dlls, or if this is even possible in an azure function?

```
IReadOnlyCollection<MetadataReference> references = new MetadataReference[] {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.4\netstandard.dll"),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.4\mscorlib.dll"),
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click "Advanced tools (Kudu)" under the "Platform features" in your azure function.

[image]

Then click "Debug console" --> "CMD" --> "site" --> "wwwroot", create a folder under wwwroot named "bin".

[image]

Drag your dll file from local to "bin" folder which you created above.

Then you can use your dll by "#r ..\bin*.dll" in azure function.

[image]